# Доступ к файловой системе из браузера...подскажите

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

1. Подскажите,если браузер (язык JS) не имеет API доступа к файловой системе (не все браузеры это могут),возможно ли написать библиотеку/механизм реализующий это на клиенте (без сервера)?
2. Может ли JS исполняемый в нативных браузерах (под win - IE,под android - WebView) связываться с API внешней библиотеки,написанной на любом другом ЯПе (c/c++,Java,Python)?

Comment: Если прям совсем-совсем нативно — не может. Максимум можно в десктопных браузерах (кроме IE, конечно же) сделать браузерное расширение с [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging), а в WebView наверное нельзя вообще ничего

Answer (score 1):

js в браузере не может работать с файловой системой пользователя.

Связываться с другими языками стоит через http запросы. Например запускаете локальный сервер на localhost:8000, со страницы открытой в Webview или просто в браузере отправляете запросы на этот локальный сервер. А этот сервер уже что хотите делает и к файловой системе обращается

Comment: Очень краткое и разумное объяснение! Спасибо! я бы еще добавил, что для простоты если сервер уже запустили - то и страницу можно прямо с него и загружать.

Comment: Вы с 99% вероятностью не сможете отправить запросы на localhost, потому что браузер заругается на отсутствие HTTPS. А настройка HTTPS на локалхосте это целая возня

Comment: ругаться на https будет только если вы основную страницу откроете по https, а вы всё по http открывайте

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='file:///C:/'>диск С</a>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]